# Authorization on an association with CanCan,Devise and Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authorization, cancan

I have the current database estructure in my application:

```
Publisher has_many videos, has_many users
Video      belongs_to publisher
User       belongs_to publisher
```

I want to be able to give permissions to the users based on the publisher, but the object that actually gets edited it's the video object.

Meaning that an User X can edit videos from publisher 1 and 2 but User Y can only edit videos from publisher 2 and 3 and so on. I'm pretty sure this can be done with the CanCan, Devise, Rolify combo.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: What is the logic connecting User X to publisher 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the delayed response. Hopefully you've figured out your problem by now, but I will provide a solution for you.

In your CanCan ability you have something like this:

```
def initialize(current_user) 
  current_user ||= User.new

  can :update, Video do |video|
    current_user.publisher_list.contains? video.publisher
  end
end
```

The above code will work if user.publisher_list returns a list of publishers a user can modify. I believe you can also do:

```
def initialize(current_user)
  current_user ||= User.new

  can :update, Video, publisher: {id: current_user.publisher_list}
end
```

Comment: I've already figured it out in a different way but this one works too! Thanks a lot.